# FireFox NumberInput and TextInput behavior when using Set() with decimal points

Tags: atata

I have a NumberInput defined thus:

```
[FindByXPath("//input[@class='form-control ']")]
public NumberInput<_> Amount { get; private set; }
```

For this input in the SUT:

```
<input id="ember293-mask" class="form-control " type="text" style="text-align: right;" im-insert="true">
```

When I use Amount.Set(123.45) it works great in Chrome, but in Firefox, it is only entering the two digits after the decimal point (the .45).  It does the same thing if I define the input as a TextInput and Set a string with a decimal point.  But, if I do Amount.Type(“123.45”) it works great on all browsers.  Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue with the latest Firefox. Works fine for me. Could you please share the part of Atata trace log where the value set happens in Firefox?

Comment: I was afraid of that - I assume it is something to do with ember.js which the SUT uses as its UI - I'll DM you the trace log later today.  Thanks for always jumping in so quick!

Comment: Sure. Maybe some issue with JS. You can also try to add few seconds to wait before value set, to ensure 100% that JS was completely initialized on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change the behavior of a field value setting. Mark the `Amount` property with either `[ValueSetUsingCharByCharTyping]` or `[ValueSetUsingScript]` attribute.

Comment: Both of them work perfectly - ValueSetUsingScript is faster, so I'll use that.  Thanks!